# Only value required using mysql command

Tags: mysql, database

I created following command to get value of Innodb_data_writes using command  show status in mysql database.

```
 mysql -u root -p**** -e  "show  status" | grep  Innodb_data_writes
```

**Current Output**: Innodb_data_writes  3

**Desired Output:** 3

How can I eliminate  Innodb_data_writes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe the output rhrough cut:

```
mysql -u root -p**** -e  "show  status" | grep  Innodb_data_writes | cut -d' ' -f2
```